How to fix collection view scrolling freezes?
I'm using this code to show the progress of downloading file in my collection view cells. Everything is working fine. And if I'm not downloading a file, I can easily scroll my collection view if I tap a collection view cell. But when I'm downloading a file I have problems with scrolling. If I touch the collections cell, my scroll view does not scroll.
my code:
import UIKit


enum DownloadStatus {
    case none
    case inProgress
    case completed
    case failed
}

struct item {
    var number: Int!
    var downloadStatus: DownloadStatus = .none
    var progress: Float = 0.0
    init(number: Int) { self.number = number }
}

var downloadQueue = [Int: [Int]]()
var masterIndex = 0

extension URLSession {
    func getSessionDescription () -> Int { return Int(self.sessionDescription!)! } // Item ID
    func getDebugDescription () -> Int { return Int(self.debugDescription)! }      // Collection ID
}

class DownloadManager : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    
    static var shared = DownloadManager()
    var identifier : Int = -1
    var collectionId : Int = -1
    var folderPath : String = ""
    typealias ProgressHandler = (Int, Int, Float) -> ()
    
    var onProgress : ProgressHandler? {
        didSet { if onProgress != nil { let _ = activate() } }
    }
    var onSuccess: ((Int) -> Void)? // <- get called when download success
    var onError: ((Error?, Int) -> Void)? // <- get called when download error
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    func activate() -> URLSession {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).background.\(NSUUID.init())")
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
        urlSession.sessionDescription = String(identifier)
        urlSession.accessibilityHint = String(collectionId)
        return urlSession
    }
    
    private func calculateProgress(session : URLSession, completionHandler : @escaping (Int, Int, Float) -> ()) {
        session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (tasks, uploads, downloads) in
            let progress = downloads.map({ (task) -> Float in
                if task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive > 0 {
                    return Float(task.countOfBytesReceived) / Float(task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive)
                } else {
                    return 0.0
                }
            })
            completionHandler(session.getSessionDescription(), Int(session.accessibilityHint!)!, progress.reduce(0.0, +))
        }
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){
        
        let stringNumb = (session.accessibilityHint ?? "hit")
        let someNumb = Int(stringNumb as String)
        
        let string1 = (session.sessionDescription ?? "hit")
        let some1 = Int(string1 as String)
        
        if let idx = downloadQueue[someNumb!]?.firstIndex(of: some1!) {
            downloadQueue[someNumb!]?.remove(at: idx)
            print("remove:: did finish :: \(downloadQueue)")
        }
        onSuccess?(collectionId) // call when download success
         
        let fileName = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        var destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appending("/\(folderPath)"))
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURLForFile, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            destinationURLForFile.appendPathComponent(String(describing: fileName!))
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
        } catch (let error) {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
            if let onProgress = onProgress {
                calculateProgress(session: session, completionHandler: onProgress)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        
        let stringNumb = (session.accessibilityHint ?? "hit")
        let someNumb = Int(stringNumb as String)
        
        let string1 = (session.sessionDescription ?? "hit")
        let some1 = Int(string1 as String)
        onError?(error, collectionId) // call when download error
        if let idx = downloadQueue[someNumb!]?.firstIndex(of: some1!) {
            downloadQueue[someNumb!]?.remove(at: idx)
            print("remove when complete:\(downloadQueue)")
        }
    }
    
}

public struct Item: Decodable, Hashable {
    let index: Int
    let title: String
    let image: String
    let backgroundColor: String
    let borderColor: String
}

public struct Section: Decodable, Hashable {
    let index: Int
    let identifier: String
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let item: [Item]
}

class CollectionController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    typealias ProgressHandler = (Int, Float) -> ()
    var onProgress : ProgressHandler?
    var items = [item]()
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>?
    let sections: [Section] = [.init(index: 0, identifier: "carouselCell", title: "title", subtitle: "sub", item: [
        Item(index: 0, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 1, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 2, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 3, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 4, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 5, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 6, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 7, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 8, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 9, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 10, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 11, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: ""),
        Item(index: 12, title: "Hello", image: "", backgroundColor: "", borderColor: "")
    ])]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createCollectionView()
        setupScrollView()
        
        let count = dataSource!.snapshot().numberOfItems
        for index in 0...count {
            items.append(item(number: index))
        }
    }
    
    func setupScrollView() {
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = createCompositionalLayout()
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
    
    func createDataSource() {
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView) { [weak self] collectionView, indexPath, item in
            guard let self = self else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
            switch self.sections[indexPath.section].identifier {
            case "carouselCell":
                let cell = self.configure(CarouselCell.self, with: item, for: indexPath)
                if indexPath.row < self.items.count { // <- update UI base on self.items
                    let item = self.items[indexPath.row]
                    switch item.downloadStatus {
                    case .inProgress:
                        cell.label.text = "\(String(format: "%.f%%", self.items[indexPath.row].progress * 100))"
                    case .completed:
                        cell.label.text = "Completed"
                    case .failed:
                        cell.label.text = "FAIL"
                    case .none:
                        break
                    }
                }
                return cell
            default:
                return self.configure(CarouselCell.self, with: item, for: indexPath)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func configure<T: SelfConfiguringCell>(_ cellType: T.Type, with item: Item, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellType.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? T else { fatalError(" — \(cellType)") }
        cell.configure(with: item)
        return cell
    }
    
    func reloadData() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        snapshot.appendSections(sections)
        for section in sections { snapshot.appendItems(section.item, toSection: section) }
        dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
    }
    
    func createCollectionView() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createCompositionalLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.register(CarouselCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CarouselCell.reuseIdentifier)
        
        createDataSource()
        reloadData()
    }
    
    func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            
            let groupWidth = (layoutEnvironment.container.contentSize.width * 1.05)/3
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(groupWidth), heightDimension: .absolute(groupWidth))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
            
            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: (layoutEnvironment.container.contentSize.height/2) - (groupWidth/2), leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
            section.interGroupSpacing = 20
            section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
            
            return section
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let directory: String = path[0]
        
        var queueArray = downloadQueue[indexPath.row+1] ?? [Int]()
        queueArray.append(indexPath.row+1)
        
        downloadQueue[indexPath.row+1] = queueArray
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://file-examples.com/storage/fec85039006734629a992d7/2017/04/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4")!
        let downloadManager = DownloadManager()
        downloadManager.identifier = indexPath.row+1
        downloadManager.collectionId = indexPath.row+1
        downloadManager.folderPath = "\(indexPath.row+1)"
        let downloadTaskLocal = downloadManager.activate().downloadTask(with: url)
        downloadTaskLocal.resume()
        
        //var item = items[indexPath.row] <- only update local value
        downloadManager.onError = { [weak self] error, row in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // change download status to .failed when download error
                self.items[row - 1].downloadStatus = .failed
                self.reloadItem(indexPath: .init(row: row - 1, section: 0))
            }
            
        }
        downloadManager.onSuccess = { [weak self] row in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // change download status to .completed when download success
                self.items[row - 1].downloadStatus = .completed
                self.reloadItem(indexPath: .init(row: row - 1, section: 0))
            }
        }
        downloadManager.onProgress = { [weak self] (row, tableId, progress) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            let row = row - 1
            //print("downloadManager.onProgress:\(row), \(tableId), \(String(format: "%.f%%", progress * 100))")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if progress <= 1.0 {
                    self.items[row].progress = progress
                    if progress == 1.0 {
                        self.items[row].downloadStatus = .completed
                    } else {
                        //cell.title.text = "\(String(format: "%.f%%", progress * 100))"
                        self.items[row].downloadStatus = .inProgress
                    }
                    self.reloadItem(indexPath: .init(row: row, section: 0))
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func reloadItem(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let needReloadItem = dataSource!.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else { return }
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        snapshot.appendSections(sections)
        for section in sections { snapshot.appendItems(section.item, toSection: section) }
        dataSource?.apply(snapshot)
        snapshot.reloadItems([needReloadItem]) // <- reload items
        dataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
    
}


protocol SelfConfiguringCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
    func configure(with: Item)
}

class CarouselCell: UICollectionViewCell, SelfConfiguringCell {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String { "carouselCell" }
    
    let label = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.backgroundColor = .green
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    func configure(with item: Item) {
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("zzzzz")
    }
}

Update
As @matt recommended:

It is up to you to debug and reduce the problem, if it remains, to a
minimal reproducible example (with an emphasis on the "minimal").

I have a problem at this line:
self.reloadItem(indexPath: .init(row: row - 1, section: 0))

in didSelectItemAt method. I tried to call it not in main queue as @Ptit Xav recommended but it didn't help

Did you check on which thread the download manager execute its data downloading ? I would say it execute on main thread.

That's called a "hitch". Apple has a lot of information about how to track down and fix hitches; look at the WWDC videos and search on "hitch".

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/understanding-hitches-in-your-app

Please don't throw all your code at us like spaghetti and say "fix this for me". It is up to you to debug and reduce the problem, if it remains, to a [mcve] (with an emphasis on the "minimal").

@PtitXav I added new code to the question after the "update" title, please check

@matt I've asked several questions already and users are asking to show all the code so they can copy it and reproduce the problem. It's hard to please everyone. But I took your advice and added new code to the question after the "update" title

I've copied and pasted the code above in a new project and can't reproduce the problem. Can you please confirm this is the actual code you have in your project? I can tap every cell and scroll fine on MacBook m1 using in the simulator.
